# Importing functions from in the same file as declared

Tags: python, function, import

I would like to place a function at the end of a script which is used in the script. This, of course, does not work as the function is not known yet. 
Can I therefore import this funtion in the same script?

If I do it like the following, I get the error " ImportError: cannot import name:'subfunction' "

```
from the_script_in_use import subfuction

a=subfunction(b)

def subfunction(value)
    do something
    return a
```

Comment: Why not placing the function at the top instead?

Comment: Sure, that is the classic way. In this case I have tons of little subfunctions which would make the script unreadable. OF course I could save them also in a different file (as I do at the moment) but they will only be used in this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this in Python is writing:

```
def main():
    b = 5
    a = subfunction(b)
    print a

def subfunction(value):
    a = value + 10
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This way you can write your code in the order you like, as long as you keep calling the function main at the end.

Comment: Thanks, that is actually quite logic.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the statement :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Which will be executed if you run this file as a script. In your case:

```
def main_function()
    a=subfunction(b)

def subfunction(value)
    do something
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_function()
```

Note there is no need to import your function. 
Doing so you can order your fonction the way you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I choose the answer from nakulbansal as he was 4 min earlier :-) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `pass` :

```
def func1():
    pass

func1()

def func1():
    print "yes"
```

But this does not actually help you run the function.